# How to move a table to secondary filegroup without losing data?

Tags: sql-server

How to move a table to another filegroup?

How to move a Heap table to another filegroup?

Do we need to move the Non-Clustered indexes to secondary filegroup after moving the table?

Which SQL Server Editions support moving of table to different filegroup?

Comment: I think this might be of some help to you: http://www.bobpusateri.com/archive/2013/03/moving-a-database-to-new-storage-with-no-downtime/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Which SQL Server Editions support moving of table to different filegroup?**

**Moving a table to another filegroup *only works with Enterprise Edition*.**

## How to move a table to another filegroup?

> **Step 1 :**
>
> Check the current filegroup of the table:

```
-- Query to check the tables and their current filegroup:

SELECT    tbl.name AS [Table Name], 
          CASE WHEN dsidx.type='FG' THEN dsidx.name ELSE '(Partitioned)' END  AS [File Group] 
FROM      sys.tables AS tbl 
JOIN      sys.indexes AS idx 
ON        idx.object_id = tbl.object_id 
AND       idx.index_id <= 1 
LEFT JOIN sys.data_spaces AS dsidx 
ON        dsidx.data_space_id = idx.data_space_id 
ORDER BY  [File Group], [Table Name]
```

> **Step 2 :**
>
> Move an existing table to the new Filegroup:

If the filegroup you want to move the table to; doesn’t already exist then please create the secondary filegroup and then move the table.

To move a table to a different filegroup involves moving the table’s clustered index to the new filegroup. The leaf level of the clustered index actually contains the table data.

*Because the leaf level of a clustered index and the data pages are the same by definition, creating a clustered index and using the ON partition_scheme_name or ON filegroup_name clause effectively moves a table from the filegroup on which the table was created to the new partition scheme or filegroup.*

So moving the clustered index can be done in a single statement using the DROP_EXISTING clause as follows:

```
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX [Index_Name] ON [SchemaName].[TableName]
(
    [ClusteredIndexKeyFields]
)WITH (DROP_EXISTING = ON, ONLINE = ON) ON [FilegroupName]
GO
```

> **Step 3:**
>
> Move the remaining Non-Clustered indexes to secondary filegroup

You have to move the Non-clustered indexes manually by using the below mentioned syntax:

```
--1st check the index information using the following sp
sp_helpindex [YourTableName]


--Now by using the following query you can move the remaining indexes to secondary filegroup
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [Index_Name] ON [SchemaName].[TableName]
(
    [IndexKeyFields]
)WITH (DROP_EXISTING = ON, ONLINE = ON) ON [FilegroupName]
GO
```

Ref: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175905.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175905(v=sql.105).aspx

> **How to move a Heap table to another filegroup?**

As far as I know the only way to move the Heap to another filegroup is to temporarily add a clustered index on the new filegroup and then drop it (if necessary).

> **Do we need to move the Non-Clustered indexes to secondary filegroup after moving the table?**

A single filegroup for both data and indexes distributes I/O proportionally according to the size of the underlying files with less complexity and administration than the separate filegroup approach

If the table has more than one indexes then after performing above steps to move the tables to another filegroup ; `sp_helpindex` will show that the clustered index is on the new filegroup, but any remaining indexes will still be on the original filegroup.

The table will continue to function normally even though other indexes are still on the original filegroup. But you should have a good reason why you want the indexes located in different filegroups.

Ref: http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/dang/archive/2008/08/01/Are-you-a-DBA-Monkey.aspx

Ref: http://www.sqlpassion.at/archive/2016/09/26/how-to-move-data-between-file-groups-in-sql-server/

Answer (score 0):

> How to move a table to another filegroup?

You need to rebuild your clustered index to new filegroup

> How to move a Heap table to another filegroup?

You need to organize it as a clustered index to new filegroup

> Do we need to move the Non-Clustered indexes to secondary filegroup after moving the table?

Yes, you can move nonclustered indexes to new filegroup.
Ent Edition Of SQL allows you to even rebuild indexes online.
Some links:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175905(v=sql.105).aspx